# Javascript send object as paramater

Tags: javascript, html, string, object

I've got a long HTML created with js and I need to pass an `onclick` event to an icon and I want to send a long object as a parameter with other needs like that:

```
var opt = "<i style='font-size:18px; color:orange; cursor:pointer;' onclick=\"barkod_onizle_dialog.apply('"+vs_id+"',"+stok_ozet+",'"+b.stok_id+"','"+$('[name=tarih]').val()+"','"+secilmis_depo+"','"+b.stok_id+"','"+seri+"','"+urun_stt+"','"+lot+"','"+b.stok_isim+"',this)\" class='fa'>&#xf06e;</i>";
```

But on my browser, I get this result :

```
barkod_onizle_dialog.apply('54',[object Object],'1508','03.10.2018','11','1508','155','2022-10-02','156','ADVIA -DIRUI R1 KABI (75 mL)',this)
```

And the error is :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I could not solve it with quote approaches.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try using `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Do a `console.log` of `stok_ozet` to see what it's value is. If not, try Paul Fitzgerald's suggestion.

Comment: yes i've already tried to see what's inside to stok_ozet object it's full and with json stringify also it stil gives me the same error

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't pass an object to a function like that.  You'd pass an identifier (which you already do) and get the object when it's needed, inside the `apply()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `stok_ozet` variable contains an object that why it shows `[object Object]` in the concatenated string, so you may need to convert it to a string during the concatenation like :

```
onclick=\"barkod_onizle_dialog.apply('"+vs_id+"',"+JSON.stringify(stok_ozet)+",'..
```

I suggest also to attach the click in your JS code if you can :

```js
var opt = "<i style='font-size:18px; color:orange; cursor:pointer;' class='fa barkod_onizle_dialog'>&#xf06e;</i>";

$('body').on('click', '.barkod_onizle_dialog', function() {
  barkod_onizle_dialog.apply(vs_id, stok_ozet, b.stok_id, $('[name=tarih]').val(), secilmis_depo, b.stok_id, seri, urun_stt, lot, b.stok_isim, this);
})
```

Comment: when i try with JSON.stringify it gives me ' barkod_onizle_dialog.apply('54',{ ' and stil the same error

Comment: Ok I see Muhammed, please show me the result of `console.log( stok_ozet );` it may help us to detect the main problem

Comment: {birim: "125", sonkullanim_tarih: "2022-10-02", recete_detay: Array(13), recete_bilgileri: {…}, etiket_ozellik: Array(1), …}  it's too long

Comment: And you want to pass all the object as a parameter?

Comment: Muhammed I hope your problem was solved, I've added another suggestion to my post, HAPPY CODING.

Comment: thank you zakaria i've found a solution wiht stringify it was beacause of my quotes

Answer (score 1):

The problem her is that you are trying to concatenate an `object` to a `string`, so the method `toString()` of this `object` is called and that's why it is represented as `[object object]`.

You need to `stringify` this `object` before trying to concatenate it, you need to use `JSON.stringify()` over your objects before concatenating them  to the `string`.

**Demo:**

```js
var obj = {a: 40, b: 60, c:'a string'};

var opt = "<i style='font-size:18px; color:orange; cursor:pointer;' onclick=\"barkod_onizle_dialog.apply('',,'','"+JSON.stringify(obj)+"','','','','','','',this)\" class='fa'>&#xf06e;</i>";
console.log(opt);
```